# Prevent Paypal from sending if input doesnt contain specific characters

Tags: jquery, html, regex, paypal

I'm trying to prevent a PayPal button on my website from sending if the input field within the form doesn't contain the special characters i want. I've been looking into regular expressions and have managed to create one which validates if using it as a HTML pattern attribute but when building this into a conditional statement it's not working.

Can anyone with help explain where i've gone wrong please?

```
$('form[action*="paypal"]').submit(function(event) {
                if ($('input[name="item_name"]').str.match('\DUM\d{10}')){
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    alert('Your Team Name must be at least 3 characters long');
                    return false;   
                }
            });
```

Comment: `'\DUM\d{10}'` is wrong. Did you try to match `\DUM10`-like string? Or `=UM10`-like string?

Comment: It should be either `/\DUM\d{10}/.test(s)` or `/\\DUM\d{10}/.test(s)`.

Comment: Hi thanks for getting back to me, no i haven't tested \DUM10 or =UM10. I only started reading about Regex last night and DUM\d{10} was the one which worked.

Comment: Where exactly should /\DUM\d{10}/.test(s) be placed in the conditional statement?

Comment: So, why escape `D` at all then? `if (/DUM\d{10}/.test($('input[name="item_name"]').str)){`. However, it does not mean that "Team Name must be at least 3 characters long". It requires at least 13.

Comment: Hi mate, sorry, the alert text doesn't represent what i'm trying to do. What i'm trying to achieve is, the user must start the input with DUM and then 10 numbers. If they don't the PayPal button will not be submitted. At the moment, it validates when the field is empty but as soon as i type anything in it goes to PayPal :(

Comment: A regex to match a string starting with `DUM` and then having 10 digits is `/^DUM\d{10}/` - no idea how you can use it in your code.